# Configuring the AuthnRequest with Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Related example: https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2.Samples/tree/main/v2/AspNetCore

My SAML configuration is below. Basically, I think I need the AuthnRequest to have some additional elements for the IdP to accept the request as the IdP is currently returning a 400 when a SAML request comes from the application. I'm unsure if this can be accomplished with Sustainsys.Saml2 or if I should go another route.

```
public static void Saml(this IConfiguration config, Saml2Options options)
{
    options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative);
    options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("<app entity id>");
    options.SPOptions.PublicOrigin = new Uri("<app base url>");

    options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
        new EntityId("<IdP entity id>"),
        options.SPOptions)
    {
        Binding = Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2BindingType.HttpPost,
        MetadataLocation = "<IdP metadata.xml>",
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
        LoadMetadata = true,
    });
}
```

For context, similar to the example, I have controller actions for initiation:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost, HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/",
    };

    return Challenge(props, Saml2Defaults.Scheme);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost, HttpGet]
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/"
    };

    return SignOut(props, Saml2Defaults.Scheme);
}
```

I used a SAML tracer to compare an unsuccessful SAML request/response initiated by a Challenge() in the application vs. a successful SAML request initiated by a secure path/redirect added to the shibboleth2.xml.

If I compare the GET requests to the IdP (referring to the AuthnRequest now), the destination & issuer are identical in both requests and AssertionConsumerServiceURL for the Sustainsys.Saml2 request is `<app base url>/Saml2/Acs` which I believe is the correct response handler.

However, I seem to be missing a few elements in AuthnRequest with Sustainsys.Saml2 like the following. For example, my successful SAML request (not using non-Sustainsys.Saml2) has a `NameIDPolicy` and two `AuthnContextClassRef`.

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="1"></samlp:NameIDPolicy>
 <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
  <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
  <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
 </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

The `AuthnRequest` tag itself also has `ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"` on it. Issuer is also set to `<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</saml:Issuer>` rather  than simply `<saml2:Issuer>...</saml2:Issuer>`.

I have tried to modify various `options.SPOptions` settings to format the request correctly. For example, I have tried this for adding the `NameIDPolicy` element:

```
options.SPOptions.NameIdPolicy = new Saml2NameIdPolicy(allowCreate: true, NameIdFormat.Unspecified);
```

And for `RequestedAuthnContext`. Though it appears I can only add one/not multiple.

```
options.SPOptions.RequestedAuthnContext = new Saml2RequestedAuthnContext(
                new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:..."),
                AuthnContextComparisonType.Minimum);
```

Results in this inside AuthnRequest:

```
 <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="minimum">
  <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:...</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
 </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

Ideally it would be this like the successful request:

```
 <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
  <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">...</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
 </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

Any ideas on how I can move forward? Would it be easier to have the secure path/shibboleth2.xml handle the SAML request and use some different method of capturing the SAML response/hooking into authentication?

Thanks!